# this pixel's microdata is incomplete or incorrectly formated schema.org

Tags: facebook, pixel, schema.org

I have created Facebook pixels, which connected well. When I run a debug tool, it selects sample items and lists them but once I try connecting the catalog to the pixel, it shows that the pixel is not ready. Below is the code:

```
<?php

    $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT products.id,products.image,products.name,products.description, product_variant.discounted_price, product_variant.price  FROM products LEFT JOIN product_variant ON products.id = product_variant.product_id where subcategory_id = 41 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 12");
    if ($results) {     
        //fetch results set as object and output HTML
        while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
            $a = $obj->price;
            $b = $obj->discounted_price;
            $epsilon = 0;

            if(!$b == $epsilon) {
                $price =  number_format($b,0);
            } else {
              $price = number_format($a,0);
            }

            //Microdata Tags        
            echo '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                  <meta itemprop="brand" content="'.$obj->made_in.'">
                  <meta itemprop="name" content="'.$obj->name.'">
                  <meta itemprop="description" content="'.$obj->description.'">
                  <meta itemprop="productID" content="'.$obj->id.'">
                  
                  <meta itemprop="url" content="https://mgcmax.com/single.php?id='.$obj->id.'">
                  <meta itemprop="image" content="https://www.vendor.mgcmax.com/'.$obj->image.'">
                  <div itemprop="value" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
                    <span itemprop="propertyID" content="item_group_id"></span>
                    <meta itemprop="value" content="Electroics"></meta>
                  </div>
                  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
                    <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition">
                    <meta itemprop="product:category" content="888">
                    
                    <meta itemprop="price" content="'.$price.'">
                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="UGX">
                    
                  </div>
                </div>';
        }
    
    }
?>
```

What could be missing for the pixels not to connect, though the debug is working?

[Results of debug tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1G75.png)

[google_product_category warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsgez.png)

Comment: Was there ever a reason for this to happen? We are facing the same issue. Microdata tags are complete and working according to debugger but Pixel still says not ready

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue here, both pixel helper tool and microdata debugger show that everything is proper, as well as several diagnostic tools in the FB business suite.

For some reason, however, the Catalog won't connect, and gives the "not ready" error.

I can also confirm it is not related to the google_product_category warning.

You can get rid of that warning by adding:

```
<meta itemprop="category" content="xxxx" />
```

The item with "item_group_id" is the facebook category, as you clearly know already.

Comment: Was there ever a reason for this? We are facing the same issue.